# Wordpress's Category & Tag is not show after choosing

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress v 6.0.1, 6.0.3

Firstly, I choose category & tag in default Post. Then, I save and publish.
After refreshed, selected category is missing. In Post list dashboard, Category & Tag is not show. How to fix it.

45sec short-clip: https://vimeo.com/779149812

[image: not selected category]

[image: category&tag not show]

In Public site screen,

```
  $category = get_the_category();
  $category = $category[0];
  $categoryName = $category->cat_name;
```

In browser console's Elements,

[image]

Comment: it's just `name` not `cat_name`

Comment: Yes, I changed to *name*, but, this error will still occur.